# Send more than one view by json

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Currently sending a single view by json this way

```
$data=array();
$View = $this->load->view('user/create',$data,true); 

    $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(
            json_encode(array(
                'success'=>true,
                'ViewSet'=>$View
                ))  
            );
```

I need to send 3 views and one query by JSON

```
$getUser=$this->Model->searchUser($id_user);
> $this->load->view('Header/header');
> $this->load->view('leftpanel/leftpanel');
> $this->load->view('user/create');
```

Thank !

Answer (score 0):

In method "view" third paramater allows you to assign this view to variable as in your first example. So you can assign all 3 views to array and convert it to JSON.

```
$data = array();
$toJson = array(
    'success' => 'true',
    'ViewSet' => array(),
);
$toJson['ViewSet']['header'] = $this->load->view('Header/header', $data, true);
$toJson['ViewSet']['leftpanel'] = $this->load->view('leftpanel/leftpanel', $data, true);
$toJson['ViewSet']['create'] = $this->load->view('user/create', $data, true);

$this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode($toJson));
```